# Failing to export properly to svg and pdf with matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, svg, matplotlib, interactive

I am trying to save a `.svg` image from an interactive path editor based on this example: [path_editor.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/path_editor.html). Saving a PNG image works just fine, but when I save to SVG or PDF, the paths are not exported.

```py
fig.savefig('out.svg')   # missing paths
fig.savefig('out.pdf')   # missing paths
fig.savefig('out.png')   # ok
```

Is there any extra step to do in order to get a working SVG file in this case?

I am using matplotlib 1.2.1 with Python 2.7.

**PNG file**:
[image: PNG export]

**SVG file**:
[image: SVG export]

### UPDATE

This is apparently a bug in matplotlib. I created [an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2005) on their github project as advised by @tcaswell.

Comment: what version of `mpl` are you using?

Comment: I am using matplotlib 1.2.1 with Python 2.7.

Comment: smells like a bug, and I can confirm it exists on master. I would create an issue on github.

Comment: @tcaswell: the pdf should support alpha, it's eps that does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a bug in `matplotlib`. A [patch](https://github.com/mdboom/matplotlib/commit/35e792f9bebc26b7445629c2d389a7f3d185ee95) has been made and the issue is solved. It has been merged in `master` and `1.2.x`.